# Unable to copy files and folders on azure while CI/CD

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am trying to deploy my node application on azure. The deployment is successful but as I check the KUDU console the files haven't updated. All the files and folders are the same as previous.

I am using Azure VSTS for CI/CD, as I tried to use "copy files" task for coping the files and "publish artifacts" task for deploying but it doesn't work. The task output in the console shows that it has copied the files but the KUDU console shows no changes.

See the screenshots for more context -
[Copy files plugin SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tn3e1.png), [Copy files description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bptO.png), [Publish artifacts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7lbS.png)

- Actual result: The files and folders are not updated on every deployment.
- Expected result: The files and folders must update on every deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Copy Files` and `Publish artifacts` tasks are part of your **Build** pipeline. The Publish artifacts task makes items you choose available as a named artifact to a **Release** pipeline, while the copy files task is usually used to explicitly separate files from the working directory into a staging directory. Technically speaking, this task isn't necessary, as the Publish artifacts task will allow you to put a source folder that doesn't need to be under the `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)`, but it is helpful to keep clutter out of build artifacts.

While **Most** of the tasks that are usable in the Build pipeline are also available in the Release pipeline, it is not true for all. It's not clear from your question, but [you should probably be using the Release pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/what-is-release-management?view=azure-devops) to actually deliver your product.

Using jobs run on [deployment groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deployment-groups/?view=azure-devops) (collections of machines that have been registered as agents), or [Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/cd/deploy-webdeploy-webapps?view=azure-devops) tasks you can specify how to get your software where it needs to go.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I am using the **Azure app service deploy** for deploying my application in the release pipeline but it does't works the results are same none of the files are updated @Josh

Comment: Can you update your question with more information about the release pipeline and how that is setup? Do you see all the relevant files in the build artifact produced by your build pipeline?

Comment: I have fixed the issue and thank you for helping, the relevant files where not updating in the build artifact. @Josh

Comment: @SAURABHRAI glad to hear you got it figured!